# Sum of different elements in dynamic list and make a descending list

Tags: prolog

So I have this homework , and the basic idea is to simulate selling books.
I have :- dynamic book/4.
book('Author','Title','City',Sales). in my dat file .
An author can have more than 1 book , and 1 book can be sold in multiple cities.I was able to simulate purchasing the books .
My problem is that I have to write out the best selling author , and the best selling city based on overall sales and also make a descending list which will write out the author , title , sales in descending order based on sales.

I tried to use findall , and forall methods but I was not able to make it work like that.

```
bestsellingauthor:- book(_,_,_,Sale), max(Eladas,All),
    writef('Most popular author is:\n'),
    forall(book(Auth,_,_,All), writef('%w - %w-db\n',[Auth,All])),menu.

stat:- forall(book(Auth,Title,_,Sale),(
              Sale > 0,
        writef('%w - %w - \t%w db \n',[Auth,Title,Sale]))).
```

So basically I would like to be able to get all of the sales of one author that may or may not have more than 1 book , and also in the stat code , I would like to write out that list in descending order based on sales.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you provide example data along with queries and results you expect?

Comment: Yes , so the example datas look like this:        book('Authone','Titleone','Cityone',235),book('Authtwo','Titletwo','Citytwo',135),book('Authone','Titlethree','Citythree',225), and the best selling author would be Authone because he sold 235 + 225 books alltogether , and after this I would like to write out each books with Author,Title,Sale , and make it into a descending list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these three facts in the database, using `bagof`, sells per entry per author:

```
?- bagof(Sold, Title^City^book(Author, Title, City, Sold), Sales).
Author = 'Authone',
Sales = [235, 225] ;
Author = 'Authtwo',
Sales = [135].
```

You can now sum the sells to obtain a total and collect these with an outer `bagof`:

```
?- bagof(Total-Author, Sales^( bagof(Sold, Title^City^book(Author, Title, City, Sold), Sales), sum_list(Sales, Total) ), Totals), sort(1, @>=, Totals, [Total_sold-Author|_]).
Author = 'Authone',
Totals = [460-'Authone', 135-'Authtwo'],
Total_sold = 460.
```

I used the 4-argument version of sort so that I can sort on first argument in reverse.

To get a list grouped by Author/Title:

```
?- bagof(Sold, City^book(Author, Title, City, Sold), Sales).
```

and to get a descending list of books by sales:

```
?- bagof(Total-book(Author, Title), Sales^( bagof(Sold, City^book(Author, Title, City, Sold), Sales), sum_list(Sales, Total) ), R), sort(1, @>=, R, Result).
R = Result, Result = [235-book('Authone', 'Titleone'), 225-book('Authone', 'Titlethree'), 135-book('Authtwo', 'Titletwo')].
```

You will make your life much easier if you used `library(aggregate)` for this. It then goes like this:

```
?- aggregate(sum(Sold), City^Title^book(Author, Title, City, Sold), Total).
Author = 'Authone',
Total = 460 ;
Author = 'Authtwo',
Total = 135.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly . I have on little question , when I am writing out the descending list is it possible to do it without the book() part ?

Comment: If you want to return both the book title and author, you'd have to put them in something. What is wrong with `book(Author, Title)`? You could name it `author_title(Author, Title)` instead, if that looks better.